# How to properly query all messages sent by current user in a specified time range in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am a Ruby beginner. I am trying to write a function (within a Rails app) that may or not allow a user to send a message, depending on their current daily quota. I call this function in the Message Controller, while it is defined in Message Model.

*Function Definition:*

```
def limit_has_been_reached(user)
        limit = 50
        messages = user.messages.find(:all, :conditions => ["created_at between ? and ?",
               Date.today - 1.day, Date.today])
        if messages.length < limit
            return false
        else
            return true
        end
    end
```

*Function Call:*

```
def create
   ...
   if !@message.limit_has_been_reached(current_user)
       send
   else 
       reject
```

That's what I have so far. My problem is, the function always returns `false`. Upon inspection, I have noticed that the query always returns an empty array. Here is what it does when run in the rails console:

```
Message Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `messages`.* FROM `messages` WHERE `messages`.`user_id` = ? AND (created_at between '2014-01-30' and '2014-01-31')  [["user_id", 1]]
```

And this is while there are many messages that the user in the example (id = 1) has sent in that time range. Can anyone please shed some light on why this could be happening? Thanks

**EDIT:**
changing line 4 in function definition to `Date.today - 1.day, DateTime.now` worked.

Comment: If your method is defined in the model you should call `current_user.limit_has_been_reached` and use `self` instead of `user` in there. I'd recommend you check the date format of your db. Test your query in a rails console until you get it right. +1 For nice formatting and explanation.

Comment: Thank you. I'll get on with the testing. However, I need to add that the function is defined in the Message model and not User. I will add this clarification to the question.

Comment: I misread that. It should be in the User model, as the behavior doesn't belong to the message.

Comment: @rlecaro2 Thanks for advising me to keep testing in console, it worked. What did it for me was changing `Date.today - 1.day`, Date.today` to `Date.today - 1.day, DateTime.now`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you create a scope:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :reached_limit, -> (self, limit) {
    self.messages.where(created_at: Date.beginning_of_day..Date.end_of_day).count >= limit
  }
end
```

Then use it this way.

```
def create
  if current_user.limit_has_been_reached?(limit)
  # ...
end
```

You probably want to store the `limit` in a costant or an attribute in this User class.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion to store the `limit` constant in the User class. I had already gotten it to work when I read your answer, but your suggestion would have solved my problem, too. What did it for me  was changing `Date.today - 1.day, Date.today` to `Date.today - 1.day, DateTime.now`. accepted.

Answer (score 1):

u have to define variable or data u have return, at the end of the method

```
def limit_has_been_reached(user)
    limit = 50
    messages = user.messages.find(:all, :conditions => ["created_at between ? and ?",
           Date.today - 1.day, Date.today])
    if messages.length < limit
        result = false
    else
        result = true
    end
    result
end
```

if u r defining the method in the model then use def self.limit_has_been_reached(user)

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestions. I have just tried both of them (putting return at end of method and defining the method with "self." at beginning) and I still get returned an empty array. I will keep testing, though.